# Submitting form data to two locations using Javascript and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, email

I have an order form that has several text areas and a single PayPal "Buy Now" submit button. I would like the PayPal button to work like usual, submitting the order to PayPal, but I would also like the same button to collect the data in the form and send it off in an email. In order to do that, though, the button would need to have two actions: sending data to PayPal, and sending data back to my php page.

It seems like this is a common problem, with no clear solution yet using solely PHP. Since I only need the data from the forms, I thought I could grab that with Javascript. I thought I could put an onClick event on the paypal button, which would call a JavaScript function that contains the PHP needed to send an email.

Is this possible? Am I way over-thinking this?

**EDIT**
Ok, so I don't want to dig into the PayPal API, since I am not comfortable with PayPal to begin with. I am thinking of another solution, which has not yet worked, but it might have potential.

The standard PayPal button code uses an input type="image" for the button. I am placing a link element around that input tag, and linking to a javascript function. For example:

```
<a href="javascript: submitForm()"> <input type="image src= ...> </a>
```

I have a form set up like this:

```
<form name="userInfo" action="sameFile.php" method="post">
```

Where "sameFile.php" is just the name of the current php file this line resides in.

Then elsewhere in the same code file I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function submitForm(){ document.forms["userInfo"].submit();}</script>
```

Where userInfo is the form with all my user input boxes. Note that "userInfo" is NOT the form which contains the PayPal button, so that might be the problem...

Anyway, this all seems to work, though I have no idea if the PayPal order is going through or not. I just get redirected back to the same php page.

Next I want to use PHP to extract the data that SHOULD be in the POST array. I enter a few test echos reporting the POST values, but the page does not load at all once I add this code. What am I doing wrong? Is there a specific place I should be putting the PHP that parses the data from the forms?

Comment: I'd submit it all to my server, parse the data, and from that point generate the email, and then send off the PayPay request.  So, the form would have a single action, and then that single action would email and do the paypal bit.

Comment: I would do it like @ernie said.
But if you want to do it with javascript, I would do it by calling a javascript function on the submit (but you need to hardcode the false value so the form isn't submitted before the function runs) and there I would call a PHP file with a form copy and then let the paypal submit work its way. 
The 'document object' is, pretty much, all you gonna need on your javascript function.

Comment: Actually, I WOULD like to do it all in PHP, if I can. I will try @ernie's suggestion, though I am not suite sure how to send the PayPal information after the standard submit. I know the data would be in the POST array, but how do I send the information to PayPal in the right format? I've never worked with PayPal before, so i am not 100% comfortable with how it works.

Comment: its been a long time since i used paypals api, but when i did it they had an api where they would post *completed* transactions + all details to a script on your server. then, you knew they actually paid instead of just going to paypals site and not finishing checkout. paypal had awesome developer documentation + a sandbox. you should read it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send a order completion mail ?

If so, write code to send mail in success page of paypal(return page in your server) - This is the actual way of doing it.

Comment: This is a good idea as well, especially if the intent is order completion, and the email should not go out until paypal has processed payment.  My suggestion was more along the lines of wanting to keep track of submitted orders, in case you wanted to verify what got processed/not processed.